# Counting of nested status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can someone tell me how can I count all status equal true in array tasks in each lists?

Next how to save result in every lists to $scope.listsTasks.completedTask = numer?

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/xPqrxE

for example

```
var listsTasks = [
{'name': 'Lista 1',
 countCompletetasks : 1,
'tasks' : [
  {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
  {'name':'drugi task','status': false},
  {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}],
   },
{'name': 'Lista 2',    
   countCompletetasks : 0,
  'tasks' : [{'name':'Pierwszy task','status': false}]},
{'name': 'Lista 3',     
  countCompletetasks : 2,
 'tasks' : [
  {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
  {'name':'drugi task','status': true},
  {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}]}];
```

Comment: how the output will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some nice functional ways to do this using `forEach`, `filter`, and `reduce`.

To simply count the number of tasks you can do this:

```
var count = listsTasks.reduce((a,c) => a+= c.tasks.filter(t => t.status).length, 0 )
```

```js
var listsTasks = [
    {'name': 'Lista 1',
    'tasks' : [
      {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
      {'name':'drugi task','status': false},
      {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}],
},
    {'name': 'Lista 2',
      'tasks' : [{'name':'Pierwszy task','status': false}]},
    {'name': 'Lista 3',
     'tasks' : [
      {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
      {'name':'drugi task','status': true},
      {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}]}];


var count = listsTasks.reduce((a,c) => a+= c.tasks.filter(t => t.status).length, 0 )

console.log("Number of completed tasks:", count)
```

To alter the the original object with counts you can:

```
listsTasks.forEach(item => item.completedTask = item.tasks.filter(t => t.status).length )
```

```js
var listsTasks = [
    {'name': 'Lista 1',
    'tasks' : [
      {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
      {'name':'drugi task','status': false},
      {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}],
},
    {'name': 'Lista 2',
      'tasks' : [{'name':'Pierwszy task','status': false}]},
    {'name': 'Lista 3',
     'tasks' : [
      {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
      {'name':'drugi task','status': true},
      {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}]}];


listsTasks.forEach(item => item.completedTask = item.tasks.filter(t => t.status).length )
console.log(listsTasks)
```

Of course if you've already altered the object with the last snippet counting is easier because you can just count the numbers you added:

```
var count = listsTasks.reduce((a, c) => a+= c.completedTask, 0)
```

```js
var listsTasks = [
    {'name': 'Lista 1',
    'tasks' : [
      {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
      {'name':'drugi task','status': false},
      {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}],
},
    {'name': 'Lista 2',
      'tasks' : [{'name':'Pierwszy task','status': false}]},
    {'name': 'Lista 3',
     'tasks' : [
      {'name':'pierwszy task','status': false},
      {'name':'drugi task','status': true},
      {'name':'trzeci task','status': true}]}];



listsTasks.forEach(item => item.completedTask = item.tasks.filter(t => t.status).length )

var count = listsTasks.reduce((a, c) => a+= c.completedTask, 0)
console.log("Number of completed tasks:", count)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, but one question because you make completed tasks for whole listsTasks,question is  can we make counting inside every object? look example if U can

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska -- unless I misunderstand, I think the second snippet does this. It adds a `completedTask` count to each object.

Comment: Yes but it Your script counts all the tasks and stores them in one variable, And I want each list to hold separately the value of the number of completed tasks, because I want to achieve when you look on main codepen there I set progress bar in each list, so I must have counted complete tasks but separately with lists

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska run the snippet number 2 and look at the output. *Each* object has a `completedTask` -- that's not one variable, that's three variables -- one for each object in the array. `{name: "Lista 1", completedTask: 1}, {"name": "Lista 2", "completedTask": 0}` etc...

Comment: ok thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you looking for but my answer will definitely help you. I'm looping through the whole list and printing the answer below. You may show it accordingly.

Angular Code: Added a new function getCurrentStatus to get the $scope.completedTask

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('colours', ($scope) => {

    $scope.listsTasks = [{
        'name': 'Lista 1',
        'tasks': [
          { 'name': 'pierwszy task', 'status': false },
          { 'name': 'drugi task', 'status': false },
          { 'name': 'trzeci task', 'status': false }],
    }, {
        'name': 'Lista 2',
        'tasks': [{ 'name': 'Pierwszy task', 'status': false }]
    },
     {
         'name': 'Lista 3',
         'tasks': [
           { 'name': 'pierwszy task', 'status': false },
           { 'name': 'drugi task', 'status': false },
           { 'name': 'trzeci task', 'status': false }]
     }];
    $scope.completedTask = [];
    $scope.getCurrentStatus = function () {

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.listsTasks.length;i++)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<$scope.listsTasks[i].tasks.length;j++)
            {
                if ($scope.listsTasks[i].tasks[j].status)
                {
                    $scope.completedTask.push($scope.listsTasks[i].tasks[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


});
```

Add this div tag in html. It will just print the list. Please decordate the data as you wanted.

```
<div>
            <h1 ng-click="getCurrentStatus()">Status Check</h1>
            {{completedTask}}
        </div>
```